# How to Set Up Time Synchronization with NTP on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: linux, ubuntu, time-synchronization, systemctl, clock-synchronization

After updating the base system with the latest available packages:

```
apt-get update -y
```

and

```
root@localhost:~# timedatectl
               Local time: Wed 2021-01-06 08:03:11 UTC
           Universal time: Wed 2021-01-06 08:03:11 UTC
                 RTC time: Wed 2021-01-06 08:03:12    
                Time zone: Etc/UTC (UTC, +0000)       
System clock synchronized: yes                        
              NTP service: active                     
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

but when I check the status of the time synchronization service with the following:

```
systemctl status systemd-timesyncd.service
```

I got this:

```
● systemd-timesyncd.service
     Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit systemd-timesyncd.service is masked.)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `timedatectl` doesn't state

```
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
```

but

```
NTP service: active
```

which suggest you are using NTP, instead.

With Ubuntu 20.04 LTS you could be running Chrony. Try e.g.

```
chronyc sources
```

Comment: What does try chronyc sources mean. I assume you are saying that if it outputs a specific thing it means that chronyc is responsible for the syncing and we should be using that? Next question is how?